# Magento 2 Custom Gride Throw Error

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-grid

I create custom grid but it throw error on console here is a screen shot 
[image: ma]

Comment: We'll be able to help you a lot better if you provide more details as to what your custom grid looks like and what you've tried so far.